# PostgreSQL: Having count greater than X within time period

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `sales` with one entry for every time an item is sold. I want to identify items that sold more than 300 within a two-day period. I have the following working query that returns those items that sold more than 300 in one day. How can I modify this query to cover two day periods?

I need to return both the date and the count. Unfortunately the column type of `sold_date` is `date` and not `date_time`.

```
select 
    item_id, sold_date, count(*) as cnt
from 
    sales
group by 
    item_id, sold_date
having 
   count(*)  > 300;
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 11.1

Example of data in `sales`:

```
item_id sold_date
102836  '2016-04-04'
102836  '2016-02-08'
102836  '2016-02-08'
102836  '2016-01-25'
102836  '2016-01-11'
102836  '2016-02-08'
102836  '2016-02-08'
102836  '2016-04-04'
102836  '2016-02-29'
102836  '2016-02-22'
102836  '2016-03-28'
102836  '2016-02-29'
```

Example of expected output:

```
item_id sold_date       cnt
130229  '2019-01-22'    '328'
81567   '2018-04-18'    '368'
76915   '2019-01-22'    '339'
95761   '2019-01-22'    '318'
84732   '2019-01-22'    '307'
83095   '2019-01-22'    '329'
101076  '2019-01-22'    '311'
84458   '2019-01-22'    '301'
84408   '2019-01-22'    '313'
97428   '2019-01-22'    '339'
```

Where sold_date in output also includes day before or day after.

Answer (score 0):

could be using  where between now and 2 day before

```
select item_id, count(*) as cnt
from  sales
where  sold_date between (now() - intervat '1 day') and now()
group by  item_id
having   count(*)  > 300;
```

for all the two day item between 2 day you could use a subquery and join

```
select item_id, count(*) as cnt
from  sales
inner join  (

  select  distinct sold_date end_date, sold_date  - intervat '2 day' start_date
  from  sales
) t on  sales between start_date and end_date
group by  item_id
having   count(*)  > 300;
```

Comment: I'm not just interested in the last two days. I trying to find all two day periods where more than 300 items where sold.

Comment: how you obtain the "two day periods" ??? .. update your question and add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: OK, I will add date sample and the expected result. How to obtain the "two day periods" is what I'm asking for help with.